# Definition of strict epimorphism

Tags: category-theory, epimorphisms

Following is the definition of *strict epimorphism* from the paper I'm reading.

[image]

However, I have some confusion. What does
$$
\mathcal{C}\xrightarrow{x}X
$$

mean? I think $\mathcal{C}$ is a category which contains $X$ as an object, so what is $x$?

And after this definition the author says that strict epimorphism + monomorphism = isomorphism. Could anyone provide me a proof?

I'm new to category theory, forgive me if the question is stupid.

By the way, I have googled the term strict epimorphism, seeing that there is few result. Even Wiki does not have this term. Is it an isolated term?

Comment: Shouldn't it be *$g$ compatible if for all $x,y$, if $fx=fy$ then $gx=gy$*?

Comment: Otherwise any monic $g$ would be compatible.

Comment: That would also be consistent with the [nLab-definition](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strict+epimorphism).

Comment: This is probably the case; I actually didn't understand _compatible_ at first, i thought it was a condition defined previously in the article ([here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0009145.pdf)) but it just means _composable_.; Then in the nLab definition, i don't really understand all that coequalizer business, but at least it refers to a precise book, Category and Sheaves by Kashiwara and Schapira, with a general and precise definition: 5.1.5 (e) p.115; with more search, one can also find a similar def. 8.10 p.59 in Theory of categories by Nicolae and Liliana Popescu without a priori unicity of

Comment: the factorization (Careful: 8.10 def. of strict monomorphism, not epi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has to read $$C \xrightarrow {x} X {\rm \ for \ any \ object\ } C\in \mathcal{C}$$ instead of $$\mathcal{C}\xrightarrow {x} X.$$

A proof that "strict epimorphism + monomorphism = isomorphism" is in the book

I. Bucur, A. Deleanu, *Introduction to the Theory of Categories and Functors*, 1970, Lemma 3.17.